# Knockout vs jQuery plugins - should they both be used?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm working on a legacy web application that was built primarily with plugins as reusable modules.  For example - when a developer needs to take a standard input box and append a dropdown next to it that modifies the contents of the input box (currency, for example, adding a $), the developer would call `$(#input).currencyDropdown(settings)`, which appends HTML (the `select` with an array of options) from within the plugin and detects changes / handles updates using standard jQuery, no knockout.

The goal of the existing pattern is to reduce copying of code - both markup and JS logic.  I'm trying to push the app more towards knockout / MVVM, but I'm not sure if this excludes plugin use.  I feel like I should be somehow replacing the target `input` with a data-bound template.  The challenge here is that in all places, all I have is an `input` and I cannot update the DOM unless it's via the plugin.

I've seen custom binding handlers used for logic / styling, but in terms of appending actual HTML markup, is a custom binding handler the right way to go?  Where should templates come into play, if at all, when reusing this pattern across multiple viewmodels in different areas of the application?

As an example, say I have an input that is not knockout data-bound:

```
<input>
```

The goal is to, from within the plugin, change this into a data-bound snippet:

```
<input data-bind='value: amount'><select data-bind='stuff here'>
```

Where `amount` is some computed observable dependent on what's selected.  As a bonus, depending on what's selected, a popup may need to be displayed.

What's the recommended strategy around knockout-ifying an application within the above constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, custom binding handlers is the way to go.